# Can't save spinner selected item to database, it saves android.sqlite.cursor@ not the string

Tags: android, sqlite, tostring

My problem is the `sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();` only saves the data as `android.database.SQLite.cursor@blablabla` ... it's not getting the string as I declared... How can I do this?

here's my code for cursor[populating the spinner]

```
 cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueSchoolAll();
    cursor.requery();
    String[] from1 = new String[]{Database.KSCHOOLCODE};
    int[] to1 = new int[]{R.id.rt1};       
    cursorAdapter =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.a_row_school, cursor, from1, to1);
    sp1.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

here's the code of the button that will save the data:

```
 String data1 = (String)sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
 mySQLiteAdapter.insertGrade(data1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
  String data1 = ((Cursor) sp1.getSelectedItem()).getString(0);
  mySQLiteAdapter.insertGrade(data1);
```

Comment: I tried your code, it doesnt save android.database..... but it only saves the id how can I change it

Comment: in getString(0) change index 0 to other coloumn index that you want to save

Comment: wooahh, works like a magic, I change it based on the arrangement of my table columns (2) and it did work much appreciated. I really appreciate your answer you've save my assignment :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to get data from cursor. 
For example:

```
public xxxxxx onItemClickFunction(..., int position,....){
int pos = cursor.getPosition();//saving the position just in case

cursor.moveToPostion(position);// moving to the position where a click is fired
String val = cursor.getString(column index);

cursor.moveToPosition(pos);// moving back to original position.

}
```

Comment: Oh... I get it so I just need to provide the position before saving it directly... I'll try it thanks :)